# Network sensor for a TCP connection for collecting statistics each second

Tags: tcp, network-monitoring, packetloss, tshark, jitter

I need a Network Sensor capable to gather basic end-to-end statistics (packet loss, jitter and network delay/RTT) of several TCP connections directed to the very same destination (ip-addr:port) on Ubuntu 12.04.
The Sensor must be able to collect such statistics with a period of 1 second. A passive sensor is preferable.

Do you have any suggestion on which tool or set of tools can be used for my purpose?

The solution I have explored so far uses **tshark**. For example:

1. I passively collect raw data of the relevant TCP connections.

   `tshark -i eth0 -f "tcp port 6666 and host 192.168.0.9" -w ./data.pcap`
2. Once the capture/experiment is done, I extract the timestamp and the delta (that should be the jitter, right?) between a packet belonging to the filter and the previous one.

   `tshark -r ./data.pcap -T fields -e frame.time_epoch -e frame.time_delta_displayed -E header=y > output.csv`

The problems are that the captured file is too heavy (a run can last ~7hours) and that I don't know how to monitor packet loss and network delay/RTT.